# Receiving message and saving it into a file in current directory

Tags: java, printwriter

This is a question about: Receiving message and saving it into a file in current directory.
My issue is that, even though the messages are received, i am unable to write them into a file. The file is updated but it is empty. Yet the messages are printed on the interface. What i want is the message to be inside the file, not printed on the interface.

This is the code

```
 public void receiveMessages() {
  File file = new File ("msgs.txt");   
  if (!file.exists()) { 
   try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
   PrintWriter printWriter = null;
  try {
   printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
   SealedObject encrypedSealedObject = null;
   while(true){
    try {
     String message = this.crypto.decryptMsg(encrypedSealedObject);
     printWriter.println(message);
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
     break;
    }
   }
  }
//catching exceptions ``here.... etc
```

}

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You aren't closing (or flushing) the `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Oh man. Thanks alot! I missed that out. Do i need to delete this post? I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- PrintWriter implements Flushable interface.

> A Flushable is a destination of data that can be flushed. The flush
>   method is invoked to write any buffered output to the underlying
>   stream.

So, you have to flush your output to the file. So, you have to use pw.flush().

- And above code will rewrite the file and not append the successive messages. If this is your requirement then its ok. But, I would suggest the following:

  ```
  PrintWriter pw = null;
  if (appendToFile) {
    pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
  } else {
    pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
  }
  ```
- No need of using 2 try and catch as in both statement you are throwing IOException. And I would suggest to throw Throwable and handle the error in top layer it's good practice and easier maintenance. A function call must only perform logic.